# How to type text to the top right of an image in Evernote

Tags: windows-7, evernote

I'm using Evernote 6.5.4 on Windows 7. I've imported a scanned image file of a lined page into a note, and I want to type out the text contained in it at the top of the document, alongside it. However, the caret won't go any further than it currently is, and no alignment options I can find will allow me to place the text higher.

[image: picture of imported image file in Evernote]

**Does anyone know how I can type text at the very top of the document, where it's more easily readable?** This seems like too obvious a feature for it not to be possible.

Comment: Have you looked at the help file, what does it suggest?

Comment: Yes, the Help contains no information on this.